# The server was not found or not accessable, This is different

Tags: sql-server, networking

***A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (Named Pipes  Provider error 40)***

The solution for the above error has been clearly mentioned on many blogs. My problem is a bit different but revolves around this error.

**On my network some computers are able to connect to SQL Server and a few computers can't connect.** I have disabled firewalls on both end for the time being but this has not resolved the issue. Please I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Comment: Is your network subnetted? Define "connect to SQL Server". Do you have the right SQL driver installed?

Comment: @Tarik I cant ping the server
ChrisP The other computers can connect to sql server and the application is working. Some computers cant connect. I am pretty sure the problem is on the system trying to connect not the SQL server

Comment: are you connecting through a name or an ip address? Could be a dns problem.

Comment: @TransactCharlie actually ipaddress/databasename

Comment: @crazyghost You wrote "cant ping" in the comment above. Did you mean "can ping"?

Comment: I meant CAN NOT PING the sql server but I can ping other systems on the same subnet

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot ping your server, and the firewall is down, the issue is network related, totally independent of SQL Server.
If you want help resolving your network issue, you will need to describe your network topology in detail.

Comment: this isn't an answer.

Comment: My computer intentionally doesn't respond to pings... is my network down?

Comment: @TransactCharlie This is the closest we can get given the facts. I am pursuing the matter further.

Comment: my computer can ping other systems on the network and websites outside the network so the problem is very specific to the system not being able to connect

Comment: @Matthew Network down is vague. Are your computers connected to the same switch? Can you determine the IP address of each machine along with network mask.

Comment: I have connected other systems with this LAN Wire they dont seem to have this problem so as I said the problem is very specific to the system

Comment: Are the IP addresses statically or dynamically allocated?

Comment: We need specific network and system configuration to nail down the problem that seems to originate from a client networking misconfiguration.

Comment: @Tarik - Dynamically allocated

Comment: Is the client getting an ip address with the proper mask, in the same subnet as the server?

Comment: I can add one info that the systems that are having connection problems are MAC systems running windows

Comment: Yes the client is getting a proper mask. If not then how are we able to browse internet on these systems

Comment: Please,  respond to my questions. Please confirm if you **can** or **cannot** ping the server.

Comment: Again, can you ping the server?

Comment: Yes I can't ping the server

Comment: CAN NOT PING THE SERVER

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We are back to investigating why you cannot ping your server. That can only be done by having enough info about your server IP, your client IP and mask, and if there exists a gateway between your client machine and your server. Leave SQL server out for now.

Comment: I really really dont think its a network problem because I have connected other systems to the LAN Wire and they seem to work fine.

Comment: Man, you cannot even ping your server. This is **obviously** a network problem.

Comment: Let me be clear, "network problem" does not necessarily mean a network infrastructure problem. Your MAC might not be properly configured network wise.

Comment: I completely understand the reason for your diagnosis and even I thought the same. So just to rule out all problems I connected another system to the lan wire used by problem system. The other  system seems to work without a glitch and it can ping the server. Thats why I am saying that its a problem in the system itself not the network. Maybe the computer name or something

Comment: Yes the MAC not being configured properly sounds reasonable and once I go back to work I can check out the MAC settings

Comment: @Tarik It seems the problem is in the system as well as the network.

Answer (score 0):

@Tarik It seems the problem is in the network firewall.
The Firewall in the network infrastructure is blocking the connection. Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the firewall or any control over network administration. Unfortunately although the problem has been solved I could not understand the root cause of this problem. The computers that we connected are assigned an IP Address dynamically and are under the same subnet but only a few computers within this subnet could not connect to the server. As far as I know the network admin did not block anything within this subnet so I am still confused and clueless as to what caused this problem